# Laravel Eloquent query for bookings

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a booking app for a hotel using Laravel.

The database used is MySQL. There is a table with all rooms and a table with reserved rooms. ReservedRooms has a foreign key to Rooms(room_id).

To get the available rooms in a certain interval i use 2 queries:

1. First I get all the rooms that are not reserved.

   ```
   $room = App\Room::whereNotIn('id',App\ReservedRoom::select('camera_id'))->get();
   ```
2. Then I check in the ReservedRooms table if reservedroom's check in/out is either lower than my checkin date or higher than my checkout date.

   ```
   $room2 = App\ReservedRoom::select('camera_id')->where([['checkin','<','mycheckin'],['checkout','<','mycheckin']])->orWhere([['checkin','>','mycheckout'],['checkout','>','mycheckout']]);
   ```

After these 2 queries I merge the results:

```
$result=$room->merge($room2);
```

The problem is that when a room is booked twice, if one of the dates is available, and the other one is not, one of the dates will pass the conditions and the room will show up in the results.

Comment: I take it that `$rr` is the same as `$room2`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change it when i made it a bit more readable. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this to get the results in a single query (according to Laravel docs [Parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping)):

```
$room = App\Room::
    whereNotIn('id',App\ReservedRoom::select('camera_id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where([['checkin','<','mycheckin'],
            'checkout','<','mycheckin']])
            ->orWhere([['checkin','>','mycheckout'], 
            ['checkout','>','mycheckout']])
        }))->get();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
However, this doesnt really solve the problem described in the post.
I need a way to avoid a room getting passed as available after it has been checked unavailable before.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The first thing I thought was that the ranges were the problem, probably something like: 
(checkin > mycheckout) and (checkout < mycheckin) in the second query can fix it.

Comment: Does this query also fetch unavailable rooms?

Comment: What I try to accomplish comparing mychekin and my checkout against checkin and checkout is to avoid unavailable rooms

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. My comment was meant for the OP.